# Running webpack build issue while trying to create a React application using babel, webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, react-router, babeljs

**I am working on a new project set up for react using webpack and babel. Following is the webpack.config.js file**

Folder structure:

```
node_modules/
src/
 - api/
 - components/
 - index.jsx
 - stats.html
webpack.config.js
babel.config.js
```

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const { ContextReplacementPlugin, HashedModuleIdsPlugin } = require('webpack');

const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

// Callback function defined on window to manage chunk loading
const WEBPACK_JSONP_CALLBACK = 'wpjpLogMeIn';

// Upper size bound for inlining PNGs as data-uris
const INLINE_IMG_LIMIT = 16 * 1024;
const INLINE_FONT_LIMIT = 16 * 1024;

// Array of modules to be split into a vendor chunk
const VENDOR_MODULES = [
    '@babel/polyfill',
    'core-js',
    'react-router',
    'react-router-dom',
    'react-redux',
    'redux'
];

// Define the filename pattern for use in JS files created by the build
// Development filenames do not include the chunkhash suffix
const OUTPUT_FILENAME = isProd
    ? 'inovmac-services-[name]-[chunkhash:8].js'
    : 'inovmac-services-[name].js';

const devtool = isProd ? 'source-map' : 'eval-source-map';

const publicPath = './src/dist/';

const outputPath = 'dist';
const imagePath = 'images';
const stylePath = 'styles';
const fontPath = 'fonts';
const scriptPath = 'javascript';

// Exclude non-English moment locales
const limitMomentLocales = new ContextReplacementPlugin(/moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en/);

const miniCssExtractPlugin = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: isProd ? `${stylePath}/[name]-[chunkhash:8].css` : `${stylePath}/[name].css`,
    chunkFilename: isProd ? `${stylePath}/[name]-[chunkhash:8].css` : `${stylePath}/[name].css`
});

const analyzer = new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
    analyzerMode: 'static',
    generateStatsFile: false,
    reportFilename: '../stats.html',
    openAnalyzer: false
});

// Ensure module IDs are deterministic (numeric IDs aren't)
const hashedModules = new HashedModuleIdsPlugin({
    hashFunction: 'sha256',
    hashDigest: 'hex',
    hashDigestLength: 8
});

const externals = {
    'prop-types': 'window.PropTypes',
    'react': 'window.React',
    'react-dom': 'window.ReactDOM',
    'react-thunk': 'window.ReactThunk'
};

const jsxIncludes = [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
];

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        vendor: VENDOR_MODULES,
        app: './src/index.jsx'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: `${scriptPath}/${OUTPUT_FILENAME}`,
        chunkFilename: `${scriptPath}/${OUTPUT_FILENAME}`,
        publicPath,
        jsonpFunction: WEBPACK_JSONP_CALLBACK
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'all',
                    test: (module) => {
                        const vendorRoot = `${__dirname}/node_modules`;

                        for (const vendorModule of VENDOR_MODULES) {
                            if (module.context && module.context.startsWith(`${vendorRoot}/${vendorModule}`)) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        runtimeChunk: {
            name: 'runtime'
        }
    },

    devtool,

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
        symlinks: false
    },

    externals,

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                include: jsxIncludes,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },

            /* Global styles (standard CSS) */
            {
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/global')
                ],
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            },

            /* Component styles (React CSS modules) */
            {
                include: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components')
                ],
                test: /\.less$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 1,
                            modules: true,
                            localIdentName: '[path]-[local]--[hash:base64:5]'
                        }
                    },
                    'less-loader'
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: INLINE_IMG_LIMIT,
                        name: imagePath + '/[name]-[md5:hash:base36:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                        limit: INLINE_FONT_LIMIT,
                        name: fontPath + '/[name]-[md5:hash:base36:8].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        miniCssExtractPlugin,
        hashedModules,
        analyzer,
        limitMomentLocales
    ]
};
```

This is my package.json scripts part,

"name": "inovmac",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "",

"main": "src/index.jsx",

"scripts": {

```
"clean": "rimraf ./dist/",

"build": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode production --progress",

"build:dev": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development",

"build:watch": "npm run clean && NODE_ENV=development webpack --mode development --watch",

"test": "npm run lint && NODE_ENV=test jest && npm run build",

"test:dev": "npm run lint && NODE_ENV=test jest",

"start": "webpack-dev-server"
```

}

But all I am seeing while serving the app is directory structure,

[localhost app view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reaMj.png)

Following is how dist folder looks like,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpyeo.png)

Please let me know what I am missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should either start the development server or else take a build by running "npm run build" and then serve the generated folder, i.e. dist. Judging by the image, it looks like you are serving your project folder. Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran the build, and also added an image to question showing how dist folder is being generated. my entry point is './src/dist'. Please take a look.